# How can I use parameter to generate dynamic secrets key reference in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use a `resolve:secretsmanager:arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1` in my cloudformation but I need to generate the name of the secret key dynamically based on the environment. so something like

```
Parameters:
 Environment:
   Type: String
   AllowedValues: ["Dev","Staging","Production"]
 DbPassword:  
   Type: String
   Default: "{{resolve:secretsmanager:arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:11111:secret:!Ref Production /applications/etl-aasdEW:SecretString:DB_PASSWORD:}}"
```

Is there a way I can define a variable within using the parameters since the parameters only takes strings and cannot take cf inbuilt functions such as fn:join

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way, unless you develop your own [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) to resolve your references in `Parameters`.